# No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, windows, ubuntu

Решил перейти с Windows на Ubuntu. Столкнулся с целой кучей проблем по переносу проекта. Теперь и в Ubuntu и в Windows Вылетает одна и та же ошибка, а точнее две.

код AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="packageName.applicationName" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="packageName.applicationName.activities.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="packageName.applicationName" />
                <action android:name="packageName.applicationName.serviceisdie" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="packageName.applicationName.activities.MainTripScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name="packageName.applicationName.activities.MainScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="packageName.applicationName.activities.TripsView"
            android:label="FuckTheOrientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="packageName.applicationName.activities.Settings"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="packageName.applicationName.activities.TlKtsm"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" />

        <service android:name="packageName.applicationName.services.GPSService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Вот лог сборки:

```
C:\Android\FuckTheOrientation\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
Error:(16, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:(17, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(18, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(21, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(35, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(40, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(50, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(53, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(16, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
Error:(17, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(18, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/AppTheme').
Error:(21, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(35, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(40, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(50, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:(53, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/app_name').
Error:Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Ошибка №1: В манифесте красным цветом стал текст:

```
http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
```

Пишет:

> URI is not registered.

Можно конечно добавить в File>Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs. И ошибка пропадёт. Но в новых проектах такого нет, добавлять ничего не надо и всё работает нормально.

Ошибка №2:
Так же ругается на следующие пункты в манифесте:

```
android:allowBackup
android:icon
android:theme
android:launchMode
android:screenOrientation
```

Пишет:

> Attribute ... is not allowed here

При чём ругается он не на основной файл манифеста, который расположен:

> ...\AppName\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

А на:

> ...\AppName\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

Пробовал и Clean Project и Rebuild Project и Invalidate Caches / Restart и ссылки проверил (@string, @style, @mipmap).

Проект очень важен для меня. Прошу помочь!

Comment: Покажите структуру Вашего проекта.

Comment: Я добавлю. Но это всё это очень похоже на борьбу с симптомами... Если этого в других проектах нет, думаю и здесь не должно быть. Даже если добавлю ошибка "attribute is not allowed here" останется.

Comment: Эта ошибка возникла, скорее всего, из-за некорректной структуры проекта.

Comment: @post_zeew Что это значит? Как её показать вам?

Comment: Нужно проверить структуру проекта. Все файлы должны находится в определенных папках.

Comment: Скриншот можете сделать.

Comment: @ post_zeew Там папок целая тонна. там скриншотов 20 нужно. Занимаюсь пока этим.

Comment: Ну если тонна, то не надо. Проверьте, по правильному ли пути лежит каждый файл. Начните проверку с `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @post_zeew Блин я уже сделал))) [фото](http://s019.radikal.ru/i643/1610/cd/80f3f33353c6.jpg). Ну не знаю. Всё вроде выглядит как обычно...

Comment: `AndroidManifest.xml` по какому пути лежит? Относительно корня проекта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47089/discussion-between-niklas1987-and-post-zeew).

Comment: А, самое главное, проверьте путь до `Android SDK` и до `JDK` в свойствах проекта.

Comment: @post_zeew До этого он действительно ругался на расположение манифеста. Говорил, что не может найти его по пути appName\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml. Пришлось в модуль в android{} явно указать где мой манифест валяется. 'sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile '\\app\\src\\main\\AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }' Что касается SDK. В файле local.properties написано _sdk.dir=C\:\\Android\\sdk_ Это правильный путь. А на счёт JDK где посмотреть путь?

Comment: В свойствах проекта в самой Android Studio.

Comment: @post_zeew Всё. Нашёл. Там тоже правильно((((( Даже ели установить\снять флажок "use ebedded JDK(recommended)" Ничего не меняется

Comment: В общем, я не нашёл другого выхода, кроме как создать новый проект и перекинуть туда весь код...((((